# Как скачать файл ssl сертификата .crt

Tags: letsencrypt

Устанавливал ssl сертификат letsencrypt через isp manager, там было расширение для выпуска бесплатного сертификата.

Сейчас доступа к isp manager нету, но на домене сертификат остался активен, есть доступ ftp и ssh к vps (cent os 6).

Где может находиться файл сертификатов **.crt** для доменов?

мне он нужен для установки вебхука телеграм бота.

Comment: Я не знаю, как устроен isp manager, но может где-то в /etc/letsencrypt? Только сертификаты не .crt, а .pem

Comment: @andreymal папка такая есть, но там только 1 файл 0000_csr-certbot.pem и это явно не он, так как у меня на vps 5 доменов и все они с сертификаатами

Comment: А папки live там нету, что ли?

Comment: @andreymal нету

Comment: Жаль, видимо isp manager всё-таки ныкает куда-то себе. В документации почему-то не написали куда

Comment: А давайте тогда с другой стороны зайдём - у вас сейчас есть apache или nginx с настроенным https? Можно было бы вытащить путь к сертификату из их файлов конфигурации

Comment: @andreymal есть, а как с него вытащить?

Comment: посмотреть и сфотографировать глазами.